# Is it possible to share ONE In-App purchase between TWO Apps?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a product that has two different build, one for iPhone, and another one for iPad.

Is it possible to **unlock features** via In-App purchase **in both** with make the playement once from one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the same ID, howerver, you can manage information about which purchases have been made by which users on your own server, and update that information every time a user buys something. You just have to check on that server which purchases have been made.

Comment: So I need to make users on my own? I cannot identify App Store users, If I'm right.

Comment: Oh, and some more important: Isn't it agains any App Store guidlines? With such a feature I can provide FREE feature unlocks for my users.