# When creating a Paid/Lite version of an iOS App, do you create multiple APP IDs in developer portal?

Tags: ios, app-store

When creating a Paid/Lite version of an iOS App, do you create multiple APP IDs in developer portal?

If you do this, do you have to create a separate group of In-App purchases as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When creating a Paid/Lite version of an iOS App, do you create
>   multiple APP IDs in developer portal?

Yes. You've got two apps, and therefore need two different app ID's.

> If you do this, do you have to create a separate group of In-App purchases as well?

See [*Is it possible to share ONE In-App purchase between TWO apps?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740399/643383). Basically, yes, you need to create a separate group of purchases, but since your server tracks who has bought what, you can link the two so that purchases made in one app carry over to the other.

Comment: Doesn't that require users register for accounts? I was under the impression that StoreKit didn't actually let you access anything resembling a user ID (i.e. tells you the "what" but not the "who"), and Apple's likely to remove support for getting the UDID.

Comment: @tc. Right -- I didn't mean to suggest that there's a way to automatically tie the purchases for the two apps together. Accounts could be one way to go.